# Can I use a function in a Django class-based view to determine template_name?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to convert my function-based view into a class-based view to clean some things up in a Django 3 app.  I've had no problem using get_context_data to work, but I can't figure out how to determine my template_name since it's normally determined from variables:
from the function based view:

```
def tour_page(request, page_safe_name, tour_id):
    site_name = request.META['HTTP_HOST']
    s = Site.objects.get(domain=site_name)
    t = Tour.objects.get(pk=tour_id)
    page_location = 'tours/' + t.tour_safe_name + '/' + page_safe_name + '.html'
    ...
    return render(request, page_location, context)
```

So.... I can do this with a function based view pretty easily.  I'm a little confused on where in a class-based view I could (or even should?) do this.  I've read some things about dispatch and potentially overriding get... but I'm not 100% sure where I should be doing this especially since I do some of this processing in the context:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    site_tour_data, s, t = self.get_site_tour_data()

    context.update(
        {
            'site_safe_name': s.site_safe_name,
            'site_name': s.site_name,
            'site_tour_data': site_tour_data,
            'tour_name': t.tour_safe_name,
            'tour_id': t.id,
            'domain': s.domain,
        }
    )
    return context
```

Is there either a way to grab it from the context or process these things out somewhere else in the loading of that particular page?  Every other view works great since they have simpler template names... it just feels silly to have a separate view for some of these more basic pages that display basic html.  It would be AWESOME if I could do something like

```
template_name = 'tours/' + self.t.tour_safe_name + '/' + self.page_safe_name + '.html'
```

but that is not a thing

Comment: Are you using a `DetailView`?

Comment: Good question!  TemplateView

Comment: If you used a DetailView or SingleObjectMixin you could access the tour object in the get_template_names method via self.object

Comment: I should note - this isn't related to a model (despite a model being used to pull the specific tour folder).

Comment: It's not a bad idea, though... let me play with that. I guess it's so detached form the model I refuse to think it through that way... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK - I was able to keep it a templateview (it's really not rest-related in any way... the tour_id is just a marker to a folder to help with white labeling).

It was as simple as overwriting get_template_names... which I thought I'd tried, but maybe I'm tired.  Thank you, Iain!

```
def get_template_names(self):
    site_tour_data, s, t = self.get_site_tour_data()
    template_name = 'tours/' + t.tour_safe_name + '/' + self.kwargs['page_safe_name'] + '.html'
    return (template_name,)
```